# How to get back the menu bar in Android Studio Hedgehog?

Tags: android-studio

Since updating to Hedgehog I only have the hamburger menu.
How can I get back the old/full menu bar?

[image: burger menu]

Answer (score 2):

You should uncheck `Enable New UI` option In Settings (Burger Menu -> File -> Settings):
[image]

Comment: In your reply/picture I see there's the option 'Show main menu in a seperate toolbar' so I can have New UI enabled (whch I like in general) but with the old menu bar. Thanks